# Mongodb insert single document returning array

Tags: mongodb, mongoskin, monk

```
var wrap = require('co-monk');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk(config.mongodb.url, config.mongodb.monk);
var sessions = wrap(db.get('sessions'));

var docId =
    yield new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        sessions.col.insert({
            title: data.title,
            views: 1,
            messages: [{
                author: new ObjectId(socket._id),
                created: new Date(),
                message: data.message
                }]
        }, function (err, doc) {
            if (err === null)
                resolve(doc[0]._id);
            reject(err);
        });
    });
```

So my question is, why is the database returning an array when only one document was inserted?

Comment: which version of node-mongodb-native (or another library?) are you using?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Currently using monk! Question updated.

Comment: Looks like a defect. Try updating to the latest monk version?